# No Output on browser

Tags: php

Hello all and thanks in advance. I am trying to create a simple script in PHP.
Not getting the actual result of $i variable. Only hello world is printing on browser.

```
<?php  
    $d = 9;
    $c = 0;

    while ($d <9)
    {
        if ($c==0){
            $i="item";
        }else {
           $i.=$count;
        }   

    echo $i;    

    $c = $c + 1;    

     echo $c;
    }
 echo  "hello world"; 
?>
```

Not able to figure out, what is missing.

Comment: Include some code so we can see what the problem might be.

Comment: You set `$d` to be 9 at the beginning, so since `$d` is never less than 9 the `while` loop doesn't run.

Comment: sorry silly mistake while ($d < 10) is giving no output at all.

Comment: You are not incrementing `$d`, so this will get stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: @GluePear is on the money.  $count is not declared either.  Try and follow the execution in your mind, use pen and paper if needed.  Think through every iteration of the while loop - think about what the variables hold each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change your while loop like this:

```
$d = 0;
    $c = 0;

    while ($d <9)
    {
        if ($c==0){
            $i="item";
        }else {
           $i.=$count;
        }   

    echo $i;    

    $c = $c + 1;    

     echo $c;
     $d++;
    }
 echo  "hello world";
```